# Object Relational Mapping api - how to - minmax function and creating tables with constraints

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, orm

I'm using the Object Relation Mapping library SQLite.Net (nuget package sqlite-net-pcl) in a Xamarin project.

I'm having a few issues that I could use help getting the answers to ...

1. I'm trying to get the max and min values from a column.  Using a different library and using string commands I could acheive this by doing ...

   ```
   private int MinMaxValues(string table, string column, string MinMax = "Max")
   {
       string selectMaxId = "Select " + MinMax + "(" + column + ") From " + table;
       SQLiteCommand selectMaxCmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectMaxId, connection);
       object val = selectMaxCmd.ExecuteScalar();
       return int.Parse(val.ToString());
   }
   ```

but using the SQLite.Net library, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing.  Trying something like this made sense ...

```
var minValue = connection.database.Query<TableFeatures>("Select MIN (" + column + ") From " + table);
```

... it returns a row match of containing zeros and nulls (which doesn't exist, so it means no match I guess).  This is how I THOUGHT I would do something like this.

2. My other issue is that when creating tables using this Object Relational Mapping api, creating tables doesn't seem to duplicate what I can do using strings.  For example creating a table using a different library by using string commands looks like this ...

   ```
       string table = "CREATE TABLE gpkg_geometry_columns(" +
                         "table_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
                         "column_name TEXT NOT NULL," +
                         "geometry_type_name TEXT NOT NULL," +
                         "srs_id INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                         "z TINYINT NOT NULL," +
                         "m TINYINT NOT NULL," +
                         "CONSTRAINT pk_geom_cols PRIMARY KEY(table_name, column_name)," +
                         "CONSTRAINT uk_gc_table_name UNIQUE(table_name)," +
                         "CONSTRAINT fk_gc_tn FOREIGN KEY(table_name) REFERENCES gpkg_contents(table_name)," +
                         "CONSTRAINT fk_gc_srs FOREIGN KEY(srs_id) REFERENCES gpkg_spatial_ref_sys(srs_id))";
   ```

... this creates a table with the correct types and constraints.  This is a geopackage table, so this string creates the table exactly as it's supposed to be constructed.  However when using the ORM api, I create a class ...

```
[SQLite.Table("gpkg_geometry_columns")]
public class TableGpkgGeometryColumns
{
    //[ForeignKey("gpkg_contents.table_name")]
    [NotNull, Unique, PrimaryKey]
    public string table_name { get; set; }

    [NotNull, PrimaryKey]
    public string column_name { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public string geometry_type_name { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("gpkg_spatial_ref_sys.srs_id")]
    [NotNull]
    public int srs_id { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public byte z { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public byte m { get; set; }

    //CONSTRAINT pk_geom_cols PRIMARY KEY(table_name, column_name),
    //CONSTRAINT uk_gc_table_name UNIQUE(table_name),
    //CONSTRAINT fk_gc_tn FOREIGN KEY(table_name) REFERENCES gpkg_contents(table_name),
    //CONSTRAINT fk_gc_srs FOREIGN KEY(srs_id) REFERENCES gpkg_spatial_ref_sys(srs_id)
}
```

and then do a

```
database.CreateTable<TableGpkgGeometryColumns>();
```

so from the string command (correct table) version to the ORM table has several issues ...

the types, string command table -> ORM table ...
text goes to varchar, tinyint goes to integer

also, looking at the database in db browser, nothing is denoted as a primary key.  Two columns should be.

I'm not clear on how to properly state foreign keys either.  I just put a placeholder in there for now.

So, basically, I can create the table using a string command with a different library, but can how can I create the exact same table using ORM?  Is it possible?  Or should I just keep creating the tables with strings using a different library?  Is that the answer?

I can query the string created tables with ORM code and it seems to work fine ... but I'd rather not mix two different approaches, unless that's the only solution.

Answer (score -1):

Your min/max method can use `ExecuteScalar` to return a primitive value and thus could be re-written as:

```
public int MinMaxValues(string table, string column, string MinMax = "MAX")
{
    var sql = $"select {MinMax}({column}) from {table}";
    return conn.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql); // assuming "conn" is a class level SQLiteConnection
}
```

As for your foreign keys, `sqlite-net-pcl` is a very lightweight ORM, and does not include those features. There are other libraries that can be used to extend its features, such as `SQLite-Net Extensions`:

- https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

You could also just continue to use those `CREATE TABLE` sql statements and execute them via `Execute` and not use the `CreateTable` method within `sqlite-net-pcl` (your choice)